# kubectl apply -f service.yml throws error

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, indentation

> error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 2: mapping values are
>   not allowed in this context

This is my service.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
 kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: eureka-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8761
      targetPort: 8761
  selector:
    app: eureka-naming-server
```

I don't know what's wrong with this service.yml. I have a running pod on Google Kubernetes with the labels: `app` `eureka-naming-server`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In YAML block styles, structure is determined by indentation. Did you space the file as follows?:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eureka-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8761
      targetPort: 8761
  selector:
    app: eureka-naming-server
```